# Cython in Ipython: ERROR: Cell magic `%%cython` not found

Tags: ipython, cython

While using `cython` in ipython notebook, I see the error below. What's wrong?

```
%load_ext cythonmagic
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/extensions/cythonmagic.py:21: UserWarning: The Cython magic has been moved to the Cython package
      warnings.warn("""The Cython magic has been moved to the Cython package""")



%%cython
def fib(int n):
    cdef int a,b,i
    for i in range(n):
        a,b=a+b,b
    return a 

ERROR: Cell magic `%%cython` not found.
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

What the warning is trying to communicate is that the extension defining the `%%cython` magic has moved to the Cython package, out of the IPython package. So instead of

```
%load_ext cythonmagic
```

you should do:

```
%load_ext Cython
```

After that, the cython magic should work as expected.

Comment: If you install the ipython with pip (i.e. without using distribution tools like Anaconda etc.), you need to install Cython module to python or virtualenv first:
`pip install Cython`

Answer (score 8):

Remember to load the extension in a different cell.

If you *load* and *use* the Cython extension in the same cell, you will fall in error:

Using the same cell:
[image: Here the function does not exist]

Using a different cell:
[image: This will work]